# Temporary files are generated when opening a file in VS 2015 Cordova App

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-cordova

I use VS 2015 Cordova app and when i open a file by double clicking the file a temporary file gets created below it [image]

How to i prevent this from happening ? The version i use is as follows

[image]

Comment: Which update of Tools for Apache Cordova are you on (a very recent install would be Update 5)?  From the above version number it looks like you are on VS 2015 RTM (not Update 1), correct?